# Polling NFS share from java breaks filesystem

Tags: java, file, share, nfs

We've got two servers having a directory mapped via NFS to each of them.

Process on server A (shell script) places file into mapped drive.

Java process on server B regularly polls mapped drive and processes the file as soon as it is found. After file is processed - it is renamed (and deleted by cron'ed process on server A afterwards)

The file is a small .properties file. Everything works well for couple of cycles. After that server A and server B start to see contents of mapped drive differently. We disabled NFS caching and attribute lookup. Problem is still there.

If I go to a server which has broken view and do:

```
ls
```

I'll see stalled files. BUT, if I do it again - correct file listing is printed.

We'd appreciate any help on the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that when looping with timer, command below stops seeng actual directory content. It gets out of sync with NFS server.

```
File[] files = dir.listFiles(new MyFileFilter() );
```

The solution I've got is to request knowingly unexisting file. I assume that this makes NFS client to fix or refresh its state.

```
// Key point is here: we ask NFS client to obtain unexisting file. Since the client
// cannot find it locally - it will make a call to the NFS server which will 
// fix client cache or whatever it uses locally when cache is disabled.
File temp = new File(dir, "unexisting.file");
temp.exists();
```

If you know the mechanism behind this workaround - please share!

Answer (score 0):

Which NFS server is used? If that server supports file change notification, you can use that instead of polling.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure - need to check NFS server. Will do this once I get to the office. What do you mean by notification? Could it somehow notify java process of a new file?

Comment: Yes, any program can register for notifications fr changes to files or new files in directories.

Comment: We use NFSv3. There are no notifications unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Which kind of caching have you disabled? NFS supports directory entry caching see the options `acdirmin` and `acdirmax` in the [nfs Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/nfs). Or the chapter "Data And Metadata Coherence" in the same manual.